# How to get Internal Speakers and Headphones Seperate in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

In one of my older computers when I right clicked on my volume control and selected "Playback Devices" it let me choose between setting my speakers default or my headphones as default which was really nice because I could disable the internal speakers completely unless I wanted them on.

I just bought a new computer and now when I open up playback devices it shows the Speakers / Headphones as a combined device.  This is a Dell Precision M6600 Any ideas on how to get them seperated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the you are connecting headphone to front panel and speaker to back panel. The problem is because your front panel is configured as HD audio port. So both are treated combined. Best solution will be to download and install audio driver. If your controller is of realtek then visit their site and install the drivers and let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: How do you find what your controller is?
I'm not sure what Front Panel or Back Panel means?

Comment: Front panel means the audio connectors on the front of your PC. Back panel is the one on the back.

Comment: Download it from here and let me know if it worked.  http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails?DriverId=T10V6&FileId=2939901298&DriverName=IDT%2092HDxxx%20HD%20Audio%2C%20v.1.16.0%2C%20A03&productCode=precision-m6600&urlProductCode=False